# How to style tables in articles page?

Tags: php, css, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I imported a database in phpMyAdmin that contains articles. I want it to be regulated, to automatically post the image, title, and contents in the articles page. And to direct it to another page when clicked.

But when rendering the articles page, the second row has two columns offset. I think it's the content of the first 2 articles that's making the problem since I did another tables with few contents in it then it renders exactly the way I want(*a row that contains 3 articles an no offset below it*).  I'm a **newbie** here, feel free to suggest if there's a better way. I genuinely appreciate it. Thank you!

```html
<div class="blogs-2" id="blogs-2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
          <?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 20";
     $result= $DBcon->query($sql);
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     ?>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0; ">
              <div class="card card-plain card-blog" style="max-height:300px;float:left;">
                <div class="card-image">
                  <a href="../news/article.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
         <img class="img img-raised" src="<?php header("Content-type: image/png"); echo $row['featured_image'] ?>" style="max-height:300px;" />
        </a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                  <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a href="../news/article.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                      <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                  <p class="card-description" style="overflow: hidden;display: -webkit-box;-webkit-line-clamp: 3;-webkit-box-orient: vertical;">
                    <?php echo $row['content']; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p class="card-description">
                    <a href="../news/article.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> Read More </a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <?php
      }
     }
     else {
      echo "<p>No News Articles to Display</p>";
     }
     ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h4 class="title">Recent News</h4>
        <ul>
          <?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM news LIMIT 5";
     $result= $DBcon->query($sql);
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<li style='list-style:none;color:black;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;'><a href='../news/article.php?id={$row['id']}'>" .$row['title']. "</a></li>";
      }
     }
     else {
      echo "<li style='list-style:none;'>No Recent News</li>";
     }
     ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div><!--row-->
  </div><!--container-->
</div><!--blogs-->
```

Comment: can you show your output?

Comment: https://ibb.co/dV5gyk it looks like this.

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: I don't want the two column space in the second row. I just want the added articles to be next to each other.

Comment: hello, php code doesn't help here, you should use some fake text and image to set up a piece of code that shows your entire structure and issue. The screen you show might be of a bad syntax structure or exactly what your css rules tell to do. Can you clarify your question ?

Comment: Without the php it works fine but when I added them to post the articles from the database, it breaks the styles just like the image.